# Twitter API get videos

Tags: android, twitter, twitterkit

I am trying to get all videos that a user uploaded using his/hers twitter account. I have tried twitter android kit and none of it's REST api has option to do so, so please help me how I can get just videos of a user.

Comment: Is there any way to get the videos? If you have already found it please answer it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no Twitter API method for this. You would need to call the user timeline endpoint and then check each Tweet for video attachments.